# Show a label when a value is selected [MPAndroidChart]

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I want to show a label with specific data when a value is selected like in the demo-Image of what I want:

[image: Image of the I want]

so I paste this code (found in the source of the exemple):

```
protected RectF mOnValueSelectedRectF = new RectF();

@Override
public void onValueSelected(Entry e, Highlight h) {

    if (e == null)
        return;

    RectF bounds = mOnValueSelectedRectF;
    mChart.getBarBounds((BarEntry) e, bounds);
    MPPointF position = mChart.getPosition(e, AxisDependency.LEFT);

    Log.i("bounds", bounds.toString());
    Log.i("position", position.toString());

    Log.i("x-index",
            "low: " + mChart.getLowestVisibleX() + ", high: "
                    + mChart.getHighestVisibleX());

    MPPointF.recycleInstance(position);
}
```

but it doesn't work, the log are displayed but nothing happen on the screen.
What I have forget or miss

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To display a marker with something inside when a value is selected we have to use a MarkerView and not the valueSelected listener.

All the necessary doc for create yours is here :
https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/IMarker-Interface

Comment: I'd like to add that there is a ready to be used marker in the MPChartExample project

Answer (score 1):

Have you written below the line in your code?

```
mChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this);
```

Comment: Yes, and when I click on my bar the listener is well called cause the logs are displayed.

Comment: it means label with value not display while you click on bar. am i right?

Comment: I wan't to display the bubble with "x: 3rd Jan y: 31.3" write inside.

Answer (score 0):

***Here is an easier solution:***

**Step 1:**
We do not need to show values over the bars so:

```
binding.barchart.setDrawValueAboveBar(false)
```

**Step 2:**
To enable values to show on bars (assuming there is only 1 barDataset in DataSet):

```
binding.barchart.data.dataSets[0].setDrawValues(true)
binding.barchart.data.dataSets[0].valueTextColor = ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(),android.R.color.transparent)
```

This will make the values appear invisibly on bars initially

**Step 3:**

```
barchart.setTouchEnabled(true)
barchart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(object : OnChartValueSelectedListener{
            override fun onValueSelected(e: Entry?, h: Highlight?) {
                if(selectedEntry!=e){
                    barchart.data.dataSets[0].setValueTextColors(getValColors(e!!.x))
                }
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected() {
                barchart.data.dataSets[0].valueTextColor = ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(),android.R.color.transparent)
            }

        })

private fun getValColors(xAxis: Float):ArrayList<Int>{
        return arrayListOf<Int>().apply {
            for(i in 0 until(23)){
                if(xAxis.toInt()==i){
                    add(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(),android.R.color.white))
                }else{
                    add(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(),android.R.color.transparent))
                }
            }
        }
    }
```